# Why does my vector have 2 additional elements?

Tags: vector, rust

I'm taking input from `stdin()` and splitting it into a `Vec<char>`

For some reason there are 2 elements at the end of my vector. Can anyone tell me why they are there and how to get rid of them?

This is where I split the input into a `Vec<char>`:

```
// Splits regEx into vector of chars
let mut reg_ex: Vec<char> = input.chars().collect();
```

This is the code iterating through the `Vec`:

```
let mut i = 0;
for character in &reg_ex {
  println!("{} {}", i, character);
  i = i + 1;
}
```

And this is the output I get with 2 extra elements at the end:

```
User input required: 
aaa
0 a
1 a
2 a
3
4
```

Comment: Probably `\r` and `\n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are on Windows these are likely the newline characters `\r\n`.

You can get rid of them by calling `.trim_end()` on `input`. Note that this would also strip any whitespace at the end of your line, if you wanted to keep that.